# How to run Mahout on Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mahout

I recently noticed that there are some discussions on running Mahout algorithms on Spark instead of MapReduce. However I couldn't find any documentation for that. Could someone tell me whether it is possible to run Mahout algorithms on Spark? If so, is there any restriction on the algorithms that we can run?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, mahout now runs on Spark (i.e. the new version [v0.10.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.mahout/mahout/0.10.0)).

The algorithms available on different engines are documented [here](http://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/algorithms.html).

These are available on Spark:

> Mahout Distributed BLAS. Distributed Row Matrix API with R and Matlab
>   like operators. Distributed ALS, SPCA, SSVD, thin-QR. Similarity
>   Analysis. User/Item-Based Collaborative Filtering. Naive Bayes
>   Classification. Stochastic SVD. PCA (via Stochastic SVD). QR
>   Decomposition. RowSimilarityJob.

Here is one of the algorithms that can be used:

```
mahout spark-itemsimilarity           \
       -i /mnt/similarity/input       \
       -o /mnt/similarity/output      \
       --master yarn-client           \
       -D:spark.executor.instances=10 \
       -D:spark.executor.cores=8
```